# Change blueprints or Reload flask app during runtime

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing a Flask app that supports a plugin architecture. Each plugin lives in a separate folder and is a module that has at least one class which subclasses a `Plugin` class. For security reasons, I don't want to load all the plugins when the flask app is initially run. Instead, the user can enable plugins from within the flask app. Once he does that, we store a memo in the database that whitelists the app for loading. However, we still have to remember which plugins are disabled and proved views for these plugins. I do that by creating a dummy class for plugins that are not enabled that don't load any custom code.

Each plugin comes with its own Blueprint. We register that when we load the plugins. The Blueprint defines a route for enabling the plugin as well.
The whole thing looks like this:

```python
for plugin_name in os.listdir(plugin_dir):
    plugin_path = os.path.join(plugin_paths, plugin_name)
    module_name = "plugins.{}.__init__".format(plugin_name)
    plugin_enabled = ask_db_whether_plugin_is_enabled(plugin_name)

    if os.path.isdir(plugin_path) and plugin_enabled:
        module = __import__(module_name)
        for plugin in load_plugins_from_module(module):
            app.register_blueprint(plugin.blueprint, url_prefix='/plugins')
    else:
        PluginCls = type(identifier, (Plugin, ), {})
        disabled_plugin = PluginCls()
        app.register_blueprint(disabled_plugin.blueprint, url_prefix='/plugins')
```

`load_plugins_from_module` looks like this:

```python
def load_plugins_from_module(module):
    def is_plugin(c):
        return inspect.isclass(c) and \
               issubclass(c, Plugin) and \
               c != Plugin

    for name, objects in inspect.getmembers(module, lambda c: inspect.ismodule(c)):
        for name, PluginCls in inspect.getmembers(objects, is_plugin):
            plugin = PluginCls()
            yield plugin
```

Now the question is the following: when I change a plugin to enabled, I basically want to  re-run

```
module = __import__(module_name)
for plugin in load_plugins_from_module(module):
    app.register_blueprint(plugin.blueprint, url_prefix='/plugins')
```

for that plugin's module so that it becomes active and registers all routes that have been defined in the subclassed plugin as well. That will raise an `AssertionError` because I can't change blueprints at runtime. What would be a good work-around for that? Can I reload the app from within the app? Can I modify the existing blueprint at runtime?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how to modify the app object at runtime but there is an alternative way that you possibly try for what you need.

- Create a table called "Plugins" and have 2 columns in it:

  ```
  Field 1: Blueprint name

  Field 2: isActive
  ```
- Provide an interface to users where they can "activate" the desired plugin. You can control access to it as needed. So you can write a view such as:

  ```
  @login_required
  def activate_plugin(name):

  #whatever code is needed to activate the flag in Plugins table.
  ```
- Blueprints can have a before_request() method that you can use to check if a plugin/blueprint is enabled. if not enable, return 404 or whatever code.

  ```
  @blueprintname.before_request
  def check_if_active(blueprintname):

      is_active = some_function_that_checks_plugin_active_flag()
      if is_active:
        #Normal processing
      else:
          abort(404)
  ```
- This way, every request to a blueprint view will first check if it is active before returning the response.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that the code in the plugins will still have to be executed - there can easily be drop db that's not behind a route, but executed whenever the module is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you would need to get this complicated.

You can simply set config options for what plugins you want enabled. And you can register your blueprints based on that configuration in your "Start_app()" method.

You can also dynamically set config options to be inherited from certain folders/files for example to make it a bit more dynamic.

Plugins are usually by developers, so a config option isn't burdensome, unless you're trying to build something where every random user can modify your website---that poses huge security issues possibly.

> For security reasons, I don't want to load all the plugins when the
>   flask app is initially run.

I'm not certain about this. Wouldn't allowing the user to manually launch plugins, be more of a security risk (so if a user secretly is able to upload code and then now he can enable them).

You can make a CMS with plugin-enabling like WordPress, by simply not routing the urls of the plugin until the user clicks "activate plugin"

Comment: Thanks. You may be right, activating stuff on runtime might not be necessary after all.