# Add new "plugin" to Flask app in runtime

Tags: python, plugins, flask

I have a Flask app with web-ui and some API for other services. I'd like to add some python package with defined interface just uploading it from UI. I can upload package, import what I need, but I cannot register new url handlers in runtime.

I've seen [Change blueprints or Reload flask app during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016060/change-blueprints-or-reload-flask-app-during-runtime) but that requires all plugins already in the system.

So I'll be glad if someone suggest a solution for that case

Comment: Spin up a new app with an application factory, then spin down the old one?

Comment: **All** URL registrations take place at runtime; not sure why you feel it doesn't work for you. What actual code did you try?

Comment: Yes, Martijn Pieters right - it works, but gives error when debug=True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually

```
app.register_blueprint(imported_plugin.plugin_handler, url_prefix=imported_config.FOO)
```

works fine in url handlers but app should be runned with debug=False